# If $x_n$ converges to $x$, then $\lim \inf(x_n+y_n)=x+\lim \inf y_n$.

Tags: real-analysis

If $x_n$ converges to $x$, then $\lim \inf(x_n+y_n)=x+\lim \inf y_n$.

I know from a previous proof that $$\lim \inf(x_n+y_n)\geq \lim \inf(x_n) + \lim \inf(y_n).$$ From there I can do the following, since $x_n$ converges to $x$,
$$\lim \inf(x_n+y_n)\geq x + \lim \inf(y_n).$$

But how do I get inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assumption*: $\lim\inf(x_n+y_n)>x+\lim\inf(y_n)$. Then
$$\begin{align*}\lim\inf(y_n)&<\lim\inf(x_n+y_n)-x\\
&=\lim\inf(x_n+y_n)+\lim\inf(-x_n)\\
&\leq \lim\inf(x_n+y_n-x_n)\\
&=\lim\inf(y_n),\end{align*}$$
(where in the 3rd line I used the inequality you already know from a previous proof) which means $\lim\inf(y_n)<\lim\inf(y_n)$. This is a contradiction!

So the assumption must be wrong which means that $\lim\inf(x_n+y_n)\leq x+\lim\inf (y_n)$. Since you already know that the same inequality holds with "$\geq$" instead of "$\leq$", both sides must in fact be equal.